# Unable to create a debug Token or sign bar files

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

The signing and debug token server has been down for more than a week and always getting "Error: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: [http://www.rim.net/Websigner/servlet/......"](http://www.rim.net/Websigner/servlet/......%22) message.

Sadly, It is impossible to build and develop apps for BB10 devices without debug tokens.

Is there any other way to get a debug token or sign bar files ?

Note: I am using Momentics IDE

Thank you

Comment: I also faced the same issue multiple times and it works randomly sometimes. May be we need to wait until the server is up again. Even I'm struggling to get the debug token. Can anyone help please ?

Comment: The debug token server should be back online and working correctly now.  Please try again.

Comment: @MSohm thanks for the update. I have just created a debug token for my device but it is valid for one year only. So, is there any other way to get a debug token after one year? 
Honestly, I am not sure if the server will be up until next year.

Comment: No, there isn't any other way to generate a debug token or to create one with a longer expiration date.